# Under what conditions can a positron exist in everyday conditions?

Tags: antimatter

I am still learning basic quantum field theory and I am curious in what circumstances could a positron exist as a stable particle like an electron or proton, say for example in a human body or a marble? I have the impression that it is unstable and has the tendency to annhilate with an electron rather quickly, but in QM everything is probabilities, so there must be a nonzero probability it can survive? What would it have to do to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

A positron is stable, just as an electron is stable. Neither one decays into other particles; an electron or positron on its own will survive forever.

The hard part is getting a positron "on its own" anywhere. There are electrons pretty much everywhere in the universe, even in interstellar and intergalactic space, and since electrons and positrons are oppositely charged its very difficult to keep them separated. When they meet, they tend to annihilate.

So there's really only one difficult condition to positron survival: don't let it touch anything.

Comment: We don't know if the electron is stable. The lower lifetime limit bounds have been estimated from experiments as >4.6e26 years and >1e39 years from astrophysical arguments. Whether positrons are nearly that stable is not known from experimental data because... as you said... it's hard to keep them around for long.

Comment: @CuriousOne Since we are in fact working more with theory here than experiment: is there any theoretical reason to expect that positrons are any less stable than electrons? What would they decay into that electrons aren't observed to?

Comment: There are fewer positrons than electrons observed in the universe. That's something that is not understood on any level of confidence and it is one of the largest challenges for both experimental high energy physics and theory. What caused this asymmetry without which there wouldn't be any matter in the universe? I don't think an explanation requires a lifetime asymmetry of electrons/positrons, though. The electrons can be the majority decay product of something heavy that left fewer positrons. My cautionary note is merely about the lack of actual experimental lifetime data.